# map_server missing a '#!' declaration at the top

Tags: navigation, mapping, ros-fuerte, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone. My launch file tries to run map_server, while got

```
Unable to launch [map_server-3]. 
If it is a script, you may be missing a '#!' declaration at the top.
```

No navigation folder in my ./ros/fuerte/stacks. So I downloaded the map_server package and "rosmake"ed it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58298/map_server-missing-a-%27#!%27-declaration-at-the-top/) by [Jorgen](https://answers.ros.org/users/4439/jorgen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [map_server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/map_server) wiki page, it looks like map_server should be a C++ binary executable.

I agree that installing the binary package as @joq suggested should be the easiest fix.  But you should also be able to download and compile from source, as you've shown above.  If you're installing from source, make sure you also have any dependencies of the "map_server" package installes as well.  "rosmake" should give errors if any dependencies are missing.  This will be handled automatically if you instal from binary .deb packages.

You can try the following tests, to see what might be missing/broken:

1. `rospack find map_server` - should list the package path
2. `rospack depends map_server` - list all required dependencies
3. `rosrun map_server map_server test_map.yaml` - manually run map_server
4. `roswtf myLauncher.launch` - check your launch file for potential errors

Hopefully, one of those will help figure out your issue!

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-18**:
You are right about map_server being a node. I was confused by the roslaunch message.